# how can i parse JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am facing some problem in parsing a json response. 
The problem is to extract the success message from the response below:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "reports": [
    { "uid": 10, "report_count": 10, "levels":1, "max_download_capacity": 10 },
    { "uid": 11, "report_count":20, "levels": 2, "max_download_capacity": 30 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `response.success` will do it assuming your response is coming via `response` var/parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse(JSONString).success`, where `JSONString` is the JSON response to be parsed:

```js
var s ='{"success":true,"reports":[{"uid":10,"report_count":10,"levels":1,"max_download_capacity":10},{"uid":11,"report_count":20,"levels":2,"max_download_capacity":30}]}'

console.log(JSON.parse(s).success);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse